# Spring roo hint extension

Tags: spring-roo

Is there a way to extend the Hint mechanism of Spring ROO?
I cam across this Jira issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO-610,
Any alternative?

thanks!

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: I am developing an add on for ROO, and I want to extend the hint mechanism so it includes the new commands I have added.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there has been not implementation of that functionality.. hint command only shows an static message checking addons.. but not third party addons..

I think that is an interesting functionality to include on ROO...

Stay tuned to Spring Roo 2.0.0 roadmap!

Best Regards,